# PrimeFaces extensions - empty value attribute

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

On my page, I have `<pe:inputNumber>` which refers to a not mandatory field. If I leave it empty, it sets the value to 0 even if I set `emptyValue = ""`. What should I do or what should I use, if this component cannot offer me that functionality?

Comment: try using `Integer`/`Long` instead of `int`/`long`

Comment: I already use Integer not int and yet the same problem

Comment: Try setting `<pe:inputNumber emptyValue="empty"` , and post your code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might need to specifically instruct JSF to interpret empty input fields as null as against coercing it to "0" with the context-param

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Additionally, for a container built on tomcat (JBoss, WSphere etc), you should set the following JVM config property (pretty easy to do within an IDE)

```
-Dorg.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO=false
```