# Disable validation, if the current UIInput component has a null or empty value

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I need to validate a length of the value held by a `UIInput` component only if the value of that `UIInput` component is either `null` or an empty.

The length validator - `<f:validateLength>` should be skipped / bypassed, in case the value is `null` or empty.

I have tried the following approach with no success.

```
<p:inputTextarea id="address" autoResize="false" value="#{testManagedBean.address}" maxlength="1000" minQueryLength="10" cols="35" rows="7">
    <f:validateLength minimum="5" maximum="1000" disabled="#{empty testManagedBean.address}"/>
</p:inputTextarea>

<p:message for="address" display="both" showSummary="false"/>
<p:commandButton value="Submit" actionListener="#{testManagedBean.action}"/>
```

The bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public final class TestManagedBean implements Serializable
{
    private String address;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public void action() {
        System.out.println("action() called.");
    }
}
```

This field - "address" is actually optional but if some users provide an input then, it should contain minimum of five characters in length.

---

**EDIT:**

I'm using `disabled="#{empty param['form:address']}"` to disable the validator, when the `UIInput` component has a null or empty value (not to dig further for a better way as this works anyway).

Comment: By putting validaateLength you're making it as required field. The other option you have is to validate this on server side in your action method.

Comment: I hope there should be some magic in OmniFaces :)

Comment: OmniFaces? Wwhat it has to do with this ?

Comment: Some in-built validator tricks may exist in OmniFaces :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, but you're not pulling the value off the component properly.

Bind the component to the page scope and retrieve the value like so:

```
<p:inputTextarea id="address" binding="#{theAddress}" autoResize="false" value="#{testManagedBean.address}" maxlength="1000" minQueryLength="10" cols="35" rows="7">
    <f:validateLength minimum="5" maximum="1000" disabled="#{empty theAddress.getSubmittedValue()}"/>
</p:inputTextarea>
```

Your current approach requires the textArea's value to be written to the backing bean. This can't happen until validation occurs (remember: `testManagedBean.address` is available only *after* successful validation); you're expecting that same value *during* validation: catch 22.

Comment: Sorry, nothing new happens by using `disabled="#{empty theAddress.getSubmittedValue()}"`. `theAddress.getSubmittedValue()`  always remains empty.

Comment: @Tiny - that's weird. Try a different condition: `#{theAddress.isLocalValueSet()}`. This returns a boolean.

Comment: `#{theAddress.isLocalValueSet()}` returns `true` even though `<p:inputTextarea>` is left blank (no input is provided to `<p:inputTextarea>`).

Comment: The validator was rightfully disabled, when I used `disabled="#{empty param['form:address']}"`. It is still inappropriate to depend directly upon request parameters.

Comment: @Tiny - I believe the reason the empty text is failing to validate properly is related to : http://stackoverflow.com/q/14607439/1530938

Answer (score 2):

No need for OmniFaces: you can create your own validator. You have to create a class that implements the `javax.faces.validator.Validator` interface, overrides the `validate()` method, and call it in your `xhtml` page. An alternative would be:

```
<p:inputTextarea id="address" autoResize="false" value="#{testManagedBean.address}" maxlength="1000" minQueryLength="10" cols="35" rows="7">
  <f:validator validatorId="myValidator"/>
</p:inputTextarea>
```

The validator class:

```
@FacesValidator("myValidator")
public class MyValidator Validator{

  @Override
  public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) 
        throws ValidatorException {
    String myValue = value.toString();
    if(myValue != null && !myValue.isEmpty() && (myValue.length() <= 5 || myValue.length() >= 1000)){
      throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
          "MyValidator Error: ", 
          "This error appears if your input has less than 5 chars or more than 1000."));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: A custom validator is the last stage. I will use a custom validator, if I find no in-built way :)